# Why does Sonar recommend avoiding Thread.sleep?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, sonarqube

According to this document (rule) S2925
https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-2925
We need to change the **`Thread.sleep`** with:

```
await().atMost(2, Duration.SECONDS).until(didTheThing())
```

Can someone give me any logical answer why we need to do that?

When this **Awaitility** class creates thread in the backend. What is the point of this rule?

Comment: sounds like you have never tried to optimize selenium scenarios where QA team stabilizes execution using `Thread.sleep(10_000)`  :(

Comment: The rule already explains itself, like all rules do: "*It creates brittle tests that can fail unpredictably depending on environment ("Passes on my machine!") or load. Don’t rely on timing*"

Answer (score 4):

Here's a logical reason for you:

```
Thread.sleep(2000);
```

will block the current thread for at least 2 seconds.

By contrast:

```
await().atMost(2, Duration.SECONDS).until(didTheThing());
```

or equivalent code will block the current thread for up to 2 seconds, and will stop waiting when the event occurs.

The latter is more responsive.

The only situation where `sleep()` might be preferable are where the thread is not waiting for an event related to another Java thread.  Even then, `sleep` may end up waiting longer than you asked for, so it is not suitable for "real time" timing.

This specific warning is in the context of test code, but the advice against using `sleep()` applies more generally.

---

I've never come across `Awaitility` before, but it seems like it is designed to make it easier to write unit tests that entail timing checks.  In the example in questions ... it appears that it would have the benefit of making your tests run faster!

And as a commenter pointed out, the [documentation](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-2925) for the rule explains the reasoning itself:

> `Thread.sleep` should not be used in tests
>
> Using `Thread.sleep` in a test is just generally a bad idea. It creates brittle tests that can fail unpredictably depending on environment ("Passes on my machine!") or load. Don't rely on timing. Use mocks or use libraries such as `Awaitility` for asynchronous testing.